# LIMIT on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-limit

How can I LIMIT the results to 10 in the following query?
I use SQLSRV.

```
SELECT Id, Firstname, Surname FROM Person WHERE Firstname LIKE ?
```

Comment: add TOP 10 after SELECT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`TOP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

`SELECT TOP 10 Id, Firstname, Surname FROM Person WHERE Firstname LIKE ?`

Answer (score 1):

use

`select top(10) Id, Firstname, Surname ....`

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by kevingessner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952811/300863) is certainly the easiest way.

I just thought I would throw some alternatives in for fun.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10

 SELECT Id, Firstname, Surname FROM Person WHERE Firstname LIKE ?

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Or a more convoluted way:

```
With q 
as 
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by Id) as rn,
        Id,
        Firstname,
        Surname 
FROM Person WHERE Firstname LIKE ?
)
Select * 
From q
where q.rn <= 10
```